# cannot send an empty message error while running a eval command

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make an `eval` command for my `discord.js` project but it's doing what it's supposed to do but it says Cannot send an empty message.

here's my command code:

```js
case 'eval':
   const result = eval(message.content.replace('>eval ', ''));
   message.channel.send(result);
break;
```

Comment: looks like you have your work cut out for you. If it cannot send an empty message, check why it's empty and change that.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca sorry your comment didn't make sense to me I'm replacing the actual command with nothing so the final result is hello if I said >eval message.channel.send('hello'); instead of it saying >eval hello..

Comment: but thats the problem, you are sending an empty string. Are you using the switch as a command handler? If so you might wanna check this out https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files

Comment: @pIOS your `eval` statement in that situation would be running `message.channel.send('hello')`, and setting `result` to the result of that code. But the method `message.channel.send()` does not return a value, so your statement `message.channel.send(result)` will give you this error because you would be trying to send an empty string. Try something like `if (result && result.length > 0) message.channel.send(result)`.

Comment: @Cannicide how do i close this now?

Comment: You do not need to close this question, it can be left open for others who may need to find the answer to this question or contribute answers of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your `eval` statement in the situation in which you use the command `>eval message.channel.send('hello')`. It would be running `message.channel.send('hello')`, and setting `result` to the result of that code.

But the method `message.channel.send()` does not return a value, so your statement `message.channel.send(result)` will give you the "cannot send an empty message" error because you would be trying to send an empty string.

So in other words, when you run that eval command, this is what's happening:
`const result = message.channel.send('hello');`

And if you were to `console.log(result)` at this point, you would find that `result` is undefined. This is why the next line, `message.channel.send(result)`, gives you the "empty message" error.

**To fix this, try something like:**
`if (result && result != "") message.channel.send(result)`

This will only attempt to send `result` if it exists and is a non-empty string. Even if that doesn't work in all cases, you just need to adjust the `if` statement to check if the result exists.

This way, if you do `>eval message.author.id` it will send you a message containing the author's ID, but if you do `>eval message.channel.send('hello')` it will not try to send an empty string in addition to sending "hello".